# Search and selecting a string in a Worksheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I know selection is not good to use. However, I need to find a string in another sheet and need it to be selected (it can even select and change the color) so the user will able to see it.

My code is only taking me to the sheet but not to the cell where the string I need to find is.

```
Sub Risk1()
    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim SearchRange As Range, cl As Range
    Dim FirstFound As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    ' Set Search value
    SearchString = "1."
    Application.FindFormat.Clear

    Sheet2.Activate

    ' loop through all sheets
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Find first instance on sheet
        Set cl = sh.Cells.Find(What:=SearchString, _
            After:=sh.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            lookat:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not cl Is Nothing Then
           FirstFound = cl.Activate.cell
        End If
    Next
 End Sub
```

The string that I am looking for can be in any cell of column A.

Comment: You are looping through sheets so do you want it to stop once you've found the first instance?

Comment: I have 3 sheets in total and the strings I will be looking for will be in only 1 sheet named Over, so The looking maybe need to be in the cells of Over sheet? I need the code to take the user in the exactly cell on sheet where the string it (the sheet is very long)

Comment: `cl.Activate` will do what you need. For me cl.Activate.cell drops an "Object required" error so you might also have an `On Error Resume Next` somwhere before that hides this error.

Comment: In total I will use 20 buttons to help the user to get the cell where the strings are located.

Comment: I am getting error `Ru-Time error '91' Object Variable or with block not set in this line `FirstFound = cl.Activate.cell`. However, any changes I try to do in the code I get different errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. If it's in one sheet no need to loop through all of them. It's still not clear to me what happens if the value is found more than once?

Btw you don't need VBA for this, the worksheet Find will do exactly this.

```
Sub Risk1()
Dim SearchString As String
Dim SearchRange As Range, cl As Range
Dim FirstFound As String
Dim sh As Worksheet

' Set Search value
SearchString = "1."
Application.FindFormat.Clear

With Sheets("Over").Columns(1)
    Set cl = .Find(What:=SearchString, After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                   lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                   MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not cl Is Nothing Then Application.Goto cl 'better than select or activate and sheet does not need to be active first
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The VBA is needed to be more fast since the sheet Over is very long.  The excel user requested a button to take them to the correct cell, there will not have double value as well. Thank you